# Proper way to communicate with parent activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I wonder what way to call for parent's(Activity) function is the proper way to go, I have a activity which starts a fragment, from this fragment I want to call aFunction() in MyActivity.

is:

```
((MyActivity) getActivity()).aFunction();
```

or simply create an interface:

```
public class aFragment extends Fragment {
  OnExampleListener mCallback;

  // MyActivity must implement this interface
  public interface OnExampleListener{
      public void aFunction();
  }
}
```

the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not per se wrong, but it's discouraged as it makes your fragment dependent of the activity, which isn't the case if you're using interfaces. Use it for testing purposes, if you're serious about writing apps, use an interface.

Read the section about Fragment to Activity communication here to use interfaces: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I read that and it says nothing about if "((MyActivity) getActivity()).aFunction();" is a bad way or not, is it?

Comment: Its a quick way to do what you want. Other ways more elegant, but thisworking fine. Same result different ways

Comment: It's not per se wrong, but it's discouraged as it makes your fragment dependent of the activity, which isn't the case if you're using interfaces. Use it for testing purposes, if you're serious about writing apps, use an interface. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Well thanks so much, I've now changed to using interfaces all through the app =)